# Find spring-data-mongo MappingContext memory leak

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, memory-leaks, spring-data-mongodb

I'm debugging a memory leak in my application which uses `spring-data-mongodb.1.9.1.RELEASE`.

`MongoMappingContext` is using up about a **third of the heap**. It has a reference to almost 30k `PersistentEntity` objects totaling over 140MB.

This memory leak is caused by holding *unnecessary* references to MongoDB data objects so they can't be garbage collected. Why might so many of these objects be held in the `MappingContext` if I never reference these `PersistentEntity` objects in my code?

Does holding on to *my* data model objects cause Spring Data MongoDB to hold onto *it's* data model objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're running into [DATACMNS-855](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-855), which has been fixed in the latest Hopper SR2.

Comment: That sounds like it alright! Can you help me understand the versioning? I am running `spring-data-commons.1.12.1.RELEASE`, that bug report was for `1.11.5`. Which version should I be shooting for?

Comment: As indicated in the ticket, the bug is fixed in Gosling SR5 (1.11.5), Hopper SR2 (1.12.2) and upcoming Ingalls M1 (1.13.0.M1). You can find more information on the version scheme in the [example on the Spring Data Releasetrain BOM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/bom), which we recommend to use over manually declaring versions for individual modules as the BOM will make sure you get matching versions. If you're a Spring Boot user, just set the `spring-data-releasetrain.version` property to `Hopper-SR2`. Upcoming Boot 1.4 will default to that.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know about `spring-data-releasetrain.version`. You're a life saver Oliver. I'll check back in if that plugs the leak.