# Possible memory leak with spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, memory-leaks, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having what I think is a memory leak with spring-data-mongodb.
Basically we're using MongoDB as a sort of cache for a RDBMS, so when the application starts we load a big chunk of the database.
So basically we are mapping/denormalising different JPA Entities to Mongo documents using different "mapping" methods like this one :

```
    @Override
    public void insertFromContacts(Set<Contact> contacts, Long seed){ 
        MutableLong sfId = new MutableLong(seed);

        List<SocialInfo> socialInfos = contacts.stream().map(c -> {
            SocialInfo socialInfo = new SocialInfo();              
            socialInfo.setId(sfId.longValue());
            socialInfo.setSearchOnly(true);
            socialInfo.setStatus(null);
            socialInfo.setContactId(c.getId());
            sfId.increment();
            return socialInfo;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        mongoTemplate.insertAll(socialInfos);
    }
```

However the memory does not stop growing, so I did a heap dump and I realise that spring is keeping a huge amount of BasicDBObject references in memory and I don't know why?
[image: java heap dump]

When checking the shortest path to the accumulation point it shows that is apparently the earlyApplicationEvents property of the class

[image: shortest path to accumulation point]

I'm using :
  - Java 8
  - Spring data mongodb 1.10.8.RELEASE
  - Spring data commons 1.13.8.RELEASE
  - Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE

Any ideas as why?

Comment: This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109957/find-spring-data-mongo-mappingcontext-memory-leak But with the versions you are giving it should be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you track down the usage of the field `earlyApplicationEvents`, it is basically for holding onto events during startup until the listeners can be registered, at which point it will get set to `null`. See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e7b77cb2b6c699b759a55cd81b345cca00ec5b64/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java#L828

You mention that you do the processing at start-up so I guess this prevents registration of the listeners until your process finishes.

If you move that initialization code further back until after the application context is fully initialized, this should fix the issue. For example registering an event listener and react on the `ContextRefreshedEvent` should do the trick. The important part is to get after the call to [`registerListeners`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e7b77cb2b6c699b759a55cd81b345cca00ec5b64/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java#L546) of the refresh process.

Comment: You were right, the initialisation was happening too soon; thank you!